# How to read the particular SMS message in univarsal windows phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone

In my project I want to read the particular SMS message and delete that message it possible in universal windows phone 10..

Is is posible using **Chat Message Access** in manifest file?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the chat messages api to access the SMS messages of your device. Using the [ChatMessageStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessagestore) you will be able to create/delete the messages but it might not be what you really want. The chat message api is more designed to create messaging application like WhatsApp.

If the message you want to receive is an app-directed message you can intercept it before it reaches the ChatMessageStore. The universal windows platform is exposing a new (restricted) API to intercept the messages before they reach the store using custom filtering rules. You can have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive). It is using the newest [SmsMessageReceivedTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.smsmessagereceivedtrigger.aspx) background task trigger.

Since this API is restricted, you will have to request the autorisation to use from Microsoft before being able to publish such an app to the store

Here is a sample about how to use the [SmsMessageReceivedTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.smsmessagereceivedtrigger.aspx) with the background task entry point and registration

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var smsDetails  = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as SmsMessageReceivedTriggerDetails;

    // consume sms
    var from = smsDetails.TextMessage.From;
    var body = smsDetails.TextMessage.Body;

    // we acknoledege the reception of the message
    smsDetails.Accept();
}

static IBackgroundTaskRegistration Register()
{
    var taskNameAndEntryPoint   = typeof(SmsInterceptor).FullName;

    var task = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == taskNameAndEntryPoint);
    if(task != null) return task;

    var filterRule      = new SmsFilterRule(SmsMessageType.App);
    filterRule.SenderNumbers.Add("111111111");
    filterRule.SenderNumbers.Add("222222222");

    var filterRules             = new SmsFilterRules(SmsFilterActionType.AcceptImmediately);
    filterRules.Rules.Add(filterRule);

    var taskBuilder             = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    taskBuilder.Name            = taskNameAndEntryPoint;
    taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint  = taskNameAndEntryPoint;
    taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new SmsMessageReceivedTrigger(filterRules));
    return taskBuilder.Register();
}
```

Since it is using a restricted API, you will have to add the following restricted capability to your appx manifest

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" 
    xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" 
    xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" 
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp r">
  <Capabilities>
    <r:Capability Name="cellularMessaging" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

You will find a complete sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive)

If you want to use the [ChatMessageStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessagestore) API, you can have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/CommunicationBlockAndFilter) which should be a good start.

Comment: The two APIs allow you to intercept incoming messages. With the first one, you will get ALL the messages (as long as they have not been filtered out). With the second one, you can set a filter (by number, content etc.) an be notified only when the message you want is received. You will have the opportunity to let the message reach the chat message store or discard it. It really depends on what you want to do : create a chat application vs receive some special content .

Comment: Hi.. i wanto read the perticular id SMS ex:ID="DM-JUNOTL" plz suggest me

Comment: If by ID you mean the phone number of the sender, you can use filterRule.SenderNumbers.Add("DM-JUNOTL"); else, you can have a look at the SmsFilterRule class which support several filter options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sms.smsfilterrule.aspx

Comment: please send me example please ..i'm not getting

Comment: Hi..Actually I'm reading the perticular ID sms ex:ID="DM-JUNOTL" But actual problem is i want to read the trigger SMS using SMS trigger.